# PLINQ ForAll broken in .NET 4.0 and 4.5

Tags: .net, multithreading, linq, task, plinq

I'm trying to come up with a way to speed up combining massive amounts of objects contained in Lists in the quickest fashion possible. Hoping to take advantage of PLINQ I attempted it but this is not a thread-safe solution. I have tested in VS2010 and VS11Beta in 4.0 and 4.5. This is my sample app. If you change BlowUp() between 1-500 it will usually work. After 500 the wheels come of the track. It will fail in multiple places. Does anyone know the fastest way to solve this problem? (Multidimensional array + PLINQ?)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PLinqBlowsUp
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BlowUp(5000);
    }

    private static void BlowUp(int blowupNum)
    {
        try
        {
            var theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData = new List<List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>>();

            //Add some test data
            Enumerable.Range(0, blowupNum).AsParallel().ForAll(row => theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData.Add(AddRowToMasterList(row)));


            var aNewRowOfData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>();
            //Add some test data
            var column = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("Title", "MyTitle");
            aNewRowOfData.Add(column);

            var anotherNewRowOfData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>();
            //Add some test data
            var columnA = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("Date", DateTime.Now);
            var columnB = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("ImportantColumn", "ImportantData");
            var columnC = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("VeryImportantColumn", "VeryImportantData");
            anotherNewRowOfData.Add(columnA);
            anotherNewRowOfData.Add(columnB);
            anotherNewRowOfData.Add(columnC);

            //Now the Problem
            aNewRowOfData.AsParallel().ForAll(anrod => theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData.ForEach(temloarod => temloarod.Add(anrod)));
            anotherNewRowOfData.AsParallel().ForAll(anrod => theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData.ForEach(temloarod => temloarod.Add(anrod)));

            //Test for number
            foreach (var masterRow in theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData)
            {
                if (masterRow.Count != 7)
                    throw new Exception("BLOW UP!!!");
            }
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private static List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>> AddRowToMasterList(int row)
    {
        var columnA = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("FirstName", "John" + row.ToString());
        var columnB = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("LastName", "Smith" + row.ToString());
        var columnC = new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>("Ssn", 123456789 + (row*10));

        var list = new List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>();
        list.Add(columnA);
        list.Add(columnB);
        list.Add(columnC);
        return list;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Taking the suggestions below... currently attempting a ForAll with a multidimensional array of KVP to provide the speed of multiple cores for this type process.

Comment: who does upvote such a question? It states 'PLinq's ForAll does not work.', which is simple not true, and only shows a misunterstanding from the questioner (which is legit; nobody knows everything, but the question is bad in its current form). What's the chance of ForAll being broken and nobody realized it until now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two problems.

- You are calling `Add` on the `theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData` instance from more than one thread without any attempt to synchronize access to it.
- You are calling `Add` on the individual `List<KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>>` items from more than one thread without any attempt to synchronize them.

You could use `lock` to protect the `Add` methods or use a `ConcurrentBag` instead. However, neither of these options are that good. The issue here is that this kind of operation cannot be parallelized very well because all of the threads will end up competing for the same lock. I highly suspect that even the low-lock `ConcurrentBag` will end up being slower than had you just punted on PLINQ and done everything on the main thread to begin with.

Answer (score 4):

This has nothing to do with PLinq - adding an item to a `List<T>` is simply not thread-safe. A workable solution that would degrade performance though would be to introduce locking. What you typically would want to do instead is projecting to a **new** collection as the result of your PLinq statement - introducing side-effects like you did is rather not in the spirit of Linq / functional programming in general and you can run into trouble (as you did).

Comment: It just seems like there was more to ForAll. If I didn't want to affect my lists in the first place I would not be ForEach/ForAll'ing them. Just makes ForAll seem pointless for lists(since I have to come up with a way to bottleneck it by locking). But doing a .ForEach to affect my collection is totally in the spirit of Linq. So why isnt .ForAll?

Answer (score 2):

PLinq is not a substitute for writing thread-safe code.  Your access to `theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData` is not thread-safe as it is being accessed by all the threads from the thread pool.  You could try locking around it, which solved the problem for me:

```
Enumerable.Range(0, blowupNum).AsParallel().ForAll(row => {
    lock (theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData) {                 
        theExistingMasterListOfAllRowsOfData.Add(AddRowToMasterList(row));
    }
});
```

However, locking might not be what you're after, since that will introduce bottlenecks.

Comment: I thought about lock but that kills the point of doing a ForAll() in the first place.

Comment: Sure, but the point is that PLink is simply another way of allocating and using multiple threads.  You have to be aware of all the pitfalls and challenges of writing multi-threaded code, whether you create your own threads, manually pull threads from the thread pool, or leverage PLink.